# read formula in another json

Tags: javascript, angular8

I am trying to make at angular 8 a way to read json and for certain cases calculate a field using an existing formula in another json.

Here's an example scenario:

```
input.json {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Joao",
        "weight": 99,
        "height": 184  }

formula.json {
       "imc": "weight/height^2",
       "abc": "(weight+10) * [ indiceY.other json]" }

result.json {   "id": 1,
        "name": "Joao",
        "weight": 99,
        "height": 184,  "formula": "imc", //or abc  
        "formula_result": 29.24  }
```

Any suggestions on how to integrate json input and formula to get the expected result?

In the final product the formulations can be altered or added ...

Comment: Hoo, boy. You definitely don't want to do it this way. For this to work, you'd need to code a lexer yourself to tokenize the arbitrary formulae, then if you're lucky you can get something like the Shunting-yard algorithm to convert it to stack-based RPN and then calculate the result from there. (Either that or use `eval`, but dear Dante please never use `eval` for arbitrary external input like this.) What reason do you have for defining formulae externally in strings like this instead of just making them functions in your code?

Comment: @IceMetalPunk Humm... 
I think of creating a user interface to manipulate the formulas and at some point I will list the data calculating the columns according to the formulas registered ... Thus the user will have autonomy to create or edit formulas.

Comment: If it's user input defining the formulas, then you *definitely* don't want to use `eval`. It'll take a bit of work, but I'd say your best bet is to re-design how your formulae are described in the JSON so that they simply list an order of operations, while the operations themselves are hard-coded by you. Your UI would then take the user's input and step-by-step translate it into this order of operations for storage in the JSON. That way you don't need to parse operations from a string, AND you don't have arbitrary instructions being run.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk
Thanks. I understand your point, but I still don't know how to apply this concept in a practical way ... I'll need to study more ...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to note that the solution adopted was to adopt the lib formula-parser.

https://github.com/handsontable/formula-parser

I'm still working on it, but no doubt this lib will help me.

thanks and good codes.